# Conditional operator in regression

Tags: r, regression, regression-coefficients

What does the conditional operator `(|)` do in the linear regression? In the following simulation, I have two sources (`s`) one of which reports 2 variables (`x,z`) and the other reports only one variable (`x`).

```
library(dplyr)
df1 <- data.frame(x = seq_len(30),  z = c(rep(NA,20), 1:10)) %>%
  mutate(
    s = ifelse(is.na(z), 1, 2),
    y = 2+3*x+5*ifelse(is.na(z), 0, z)
  )
```

I want the model to read `z` only when it is available and ignore it otherwise. However when i run `lm(y~x+z|s, data = df1)` I get only intercept term without the coefficients.

```
# Call:
# lm(formula = y ~ x + z | s, data = df1)
#
# Coefficients:
#   (Intercept)  x + z | sTRUE  
#         57.67             NA
```

I also tried `lm(y~x+z*s, data = df1)` and `lm(y~x+z:s, data = df1)` but do not get the result I was expecting.

How is this kind data modeled if not with conditional operator or interaction term? Any pointers would be helpful.

Comment: I assume you know that the "conditional operator" gives the probability distribution for the random variable z when x is a known fixed value. When x is not known the distribution for z could differ from the conditional one.

Comment: @MichaelChernick You are correct naturally about standard probability notation, but the question is entirely about R syntax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`|` means 'group by' and I'm not sure but I don't think it is used in `lm` at all. In a mixed effects model, it is used to define the random effect. That is, a different random effect is fitted for each value. e.g.

```
model <- lme(distance ~ age, Orthodont, random = ~ age | Subject)
ranef(model)
```

where a different random effect for age is fitted for each Subject.

In the example in your question, you are using it in its other meaning of "OR", so you are including a logical in each observation that evaluates to TRUE if (x+z) or s is greater than 0. This is not what you want (I assume). Your model output is telling you that for all cases where `x+z | s` evaluates to `TRUE` has an NA additional intercept.

I think you want the interaction between z and s, which is written `z:s`. Note the different operator. Note that `z*s` is shorthand for `z + s + z:s` which is probably why you were getting answers that you weren't expecting as you are including fixed effects for `z`, `s` and the interaction.

Comment: Strangely x+z:s also gives me the same coefficients as x+z*s.

Comment: Unless you have changed your default na.action option, you are excluding all rows with any NA values (i.e. all of your source 1 in your example). You need to set these to a value (probably zero) to include them. Second, you want s to be a factor `df1$s <- factor(df1$s`. This will give you an intercept, the coefficient of `x` the coefficient of `z:s1` which is NA given that all `z:s1` are zero and the coefficient of `z:s2` which is the extra effect of z when source is 2 is in the model. I get 2, 3, NA, 5 for (intercept), `x`, `z:s1`, `z:s2` in that order (which matches the generator).

Comment: Thank you. Coding `z` to `0` instead of `NA` gives the expected results.